# PrimeFaces dialog doesn't working with datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I followed here [Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf) but I don't know why  doesn't working. It took me 3 days to solve but I can't figure out what wrong in my code. Hope anyone suggest me.

I'm using Hibernate + JSF 2.0 + PrimeFaces 3.5.

**xhtml**

```xml
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable id="customers" var="customer" value="#{customerBean.customer}">

        <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.firstName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.lastName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.dob}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.email}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:4%">
            <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}" target="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false" id="carDlg"
              showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">

            <h:outputText value="Model:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.firstName}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

            <h:outputText value="Year:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.lastName}" style="font-weight:bold"/>


            <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.dob}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

            <h:outputText value="Color:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.email}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

        </h:panelGrid>

    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

**customerBean (RequestScoped)**

```
public class customerBean {

    private List<Customer> customer;
    private Customer selectedCustomer;

    /** Creates a new instance of customerBean */
    public customerBean() {
        customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();        
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        CustomersDao cust_dao = new CustomersDao();
        customer = cust_dao.findAll();
        return customer;
    }

    public Customer getSelectedCustomer() {
        return selectedCustomer;
    }

    public void setSelectedCustomer(Customer selectedCustomer) {
        this.selectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, consider having two forms, one for the table itself and other one for the dialog. After having done that, give more details of your problem. Is `customerBean#setSelectedCustomer` being properly called? What's `doesn't working` for you, that the dialog is simply not displaying?

Comment: @XtremeBiker yes bro, binding value works fine but dialog is not displaying. But Makky said that my code works very well. It tooks me 3 days but i can't figure out what wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Having tested your code, can confirm that definitely doesn't seem to have any problem (even you could improve it having separate forms). Here you have the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which works for me, give it a try yourself (you should try to minimize the problem, you could better start with something that works properly and adapt it to your concrete case).

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6479501676353748761L;

    private Customer selectedCustomer;

    private List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(new Customer("Andy",
            "Brown", "A", "abrown@email.com"), new Customer("George", "Walter",
            "B", "gwalter@email.com"));

    public Customer getSelectedCustomer() {
        return selectedCustomer;
    }

    public void setSelectedCustomer(Customer selectedCustomer) {
        this.selectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public class Customer {

        public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String dob,
                String email) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.dob = dob;
            this.email = email;
        }

        private String firstName;

        private String lastName;

        private String dob;

        private String email;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getDob() {
            return dob;
        }

        public void setDob(String dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }

}
```

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head />

<h:body>

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="customers" var="customer"
            value="#{customerBean.customers}">

            <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:24%">
                <h:outputText value="#{customer.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:24%">
                <h:outputText value="#{customer.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:24%">
                <h:outputText value="#{customer.dob}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:24%">
                <h:outputText value="#{customer.email}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:4%">
                <p:commandButton id="selectButton" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"
                    icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" update=":carDlg">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}"
                        target="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"
        id="carDlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
        <h:form id="dialog_form">

            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4"
                style="margin:0 auto;">

                <h:outputText value="Model:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.firstName}"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />

                <h:outputText value="Year:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.lastName}"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />


                <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.dob}"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />

                <h:outputText value="Color:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.email}"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just copy-paste this to your project, see it works and adapt it to what you're doing.

Comment: your code works very well, i just implemented Serializable and change scope to view but it still doesn't working. Do you need my project to check it.

Comment: yes, it works very well. My code only binding value works. Can I send you my project to check it.

Comment: Don't have time to configure/launch/check your project. However, being the code I posted very similar to yours, why don't you use mine to start implementing your functionalities? Just use mine as the base and add everything what you need, not in the other way.

Answer (score 0):

try changing var name **var="*customer*" value="#{customerBean.*customer*}"**

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works. `Debug` with `FireBug` and see if there is any error.

Comment: Really? But I can't see dialog displaying. I really don't know why?

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42652/myvbhelp